# Django field validation in Model and in Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-validation

I want to define my own validation routine for a particular field of a Django model. 
I want the error message to be displayed in the admin form but I also want the same validation to take place if the entity is saved by own python code. 
Is there a way to do this without breaking the DRY principle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to validate an individual field, you can [write a validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#writing-validators) and add it to your model field.

The validator will be run for the field whenever the model's [`full_clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) method is called. It will be run whenever a model form is validated (including in the Django admin), but it will not automatically run when the model instance is saved - you must call `full_clean` manually in python code.

```
m = MyModel(x=20)
m.full_clean() # may raise ValidationError
m.save()
```

If you wanted to force the validator to run whenever the model is saved, then you could override the save method and call `full_clean` there. Note that this would cause the validation to run twice when using model forms and the django admin.