# django model validation without using modelform

Tags: django, django-models

I wanted to do field validation on a django model without using ModelForms. 
Is there a way I can get the clean_fieldname method to be called when save() is invoked?

Comment: You could declare any custom form and write a clean method yourself. Then you can overwrite the Form save() method and make it save, delete, or do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clean_fieldname` method belongs on a form or a model form. There's no code in the model to do the same thing, you'd have to implement it yourself.

I recommend you write a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/) for your field, then call [full_clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) before saving to validate your instance.

Comment: Thanks calling full_clean() will do the work. Is there a cleaner way like validators to write data manipulator get it automatically called on save() as well apart from full_clean()?

Comment: I've [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945339/is-this-the-way-to-validate-django-model-fields/12945692#12945692) [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771029/django-raise-a-validation-error-in-a-models-save-method) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608639/django-field-validation-in-model-and-in-admin) on stack overflow before, hopefully they'll help explain further.